# I want to use the FILTER function in Excel to return the last points scored in the last 10 games based on player name

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have a dataset with all NBA players for the 4 seasons.  I want to be able to filter the data based on the player and their points for the last 3, 5, 10, and 20 games.  I'd like the date of each instance to appear as well.

I have tried various formulas such as
=filter(Z:Z,E:E=BI1) which will print all the points for the player.  I only want to print the number of games specified in a cell

I would also like to accomplish the same by filtering home/away, and vs the upcoming opponent based on last 3, 5, 10, and 20 games

I would be happy to share the dataset if need be

[image]

In a different sheet (labeled PROPS) I have a drop down list with all the players' names.  I want to select a name from the drop down in cell A2, and in cells B3:E12 list the results of the last # of games based on the number in cell B2.  I can get the results for all games, however it prints the first 10 games and I want the last 10 games.

Sorry I hope this helps.

Here is the desired output.
[image]

Comment: Put few of a sample data and show your desired output.

Comment: Also, your question is really multiple questions. Make sure you formulate your question properly, choose one subject and share some dummy data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables . Please also mention what your expected result is with given sample data.

Comment: Just updated my post.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Filter Data

```
=LET(data,Sheet1!A2:AA21,player,A2,last_games,B2,
        player_col,5,return_cols,{3;5;26},
TAKE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,return_cols),
    CHOOSECOLS(data,player_col)=player),-last_games))
```

i.e.

```
=LET(data,Sheet1!A2:AA21,
TAKE(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data,{3;5;26}),
    CHOOSECOLS(data,5)=A2),-B2))
```

[image]

Comment: what is the range for "data"?

Comment: Range for data is `Sheet1!A2:AA21`